# Snapshot 1.8 dependecies error on tripleplay examples

Tags: playn, tripleplay

i'm trying to run the tripleplay examples in my eclipse (https://github.com/threerings/tripleplay) but it always sows me te same error during installation:

```
Failed to execute goal on project tripleplay: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.threerings:tripleplay:jar:1.8-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.googlecode.playn:playn-core:jar:1.8-SNAPSHOT, com.googlecode.playn:playn-java:jar:1.8-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.googlecode.playn:playn-core:jar:1.8-SNAPSHOT in http://forplay.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of forplay-legacy has elapsed or updates are forced
```

I`ve forced to update maven dependencies but it didn't work... Anybody knows how to solve this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to checkout also the threerings fork of Playn:
https://github.com/threerings/playn
and launch a mvn clean install on that project.

Answer (score 0):

I created a maven repository who contain this dependencies,

feel free to use it

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
     <id>bubuntux-repo</id> <!--Contains PlayN and Tripleplay snapshots-->
     <url>http://repository-bubuntux.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/</url>
   </repository>
</repositories>
```

Keep in mind to this artifact are spanshots from the Threerings repositories and my CI doesn't run any test unit, it just compile, so the library can be a little unestable.